# Download CSV from GAE app using OAuth

Tags: google-app-engine, csv, oauth, google-apps-script

I need to download a CSV available via OAuth from a GAE application i own. Here is the Google Apps Script :

```
function getFile(fileURL) {

  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService('google');  
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl('https://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetAccessToken');  
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl('https://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthGetRequestToken');  
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl('https://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/OAuthAuthorizeToken'); 

  var options = {};
  options.method = 'GET';
  options.oAuthServiceName = 'google';
  options.oAuthUseToken = 'always';
  options.muteHttpExceptions = true

  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  try {
    var fileURL = 'https://my-app.appspot.com/oauth/na/productusage';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL, options);
    Logger.log(response.getAllHeaders().toSource());
    Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
    var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
    var folder = DocsList.getFolder('Download');
    var result = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
    result.rename('ProductUsage-' + formattedDate +'.csv');
  } catch (e) {
  Logger.log(e)

  }
}
```

I already used this script to download another CSV file from the same GAE app, so the authentication should work. However in that case, it's not working, here is the given error :
[14-02-27 17:20:20:120 CET] Exception: Failed to authenticate for service: google

I don't understand why, if i change the fileURL to another CSV file from the same GAE app, it's downloading.

More infos:

- The file is bigger than the other: ~6MB.
- We own Google apps for
  business.